# translating and scaling viewport to fit geojson map in D3js

Tags: javascript, geojson, d3

I am trying to load a map of Rio de Janeiro (Brazil) in GeoJson for with D3js

the code and the map is here:
https://gist.github.com/4157853

I can open the map normally with Qgis, but with d3js nothing appears in the SVG canvas.
My projection is epsg4326, the same as google maps. and the units are in lat/long.

What am I doing Wrong?